# How write a new MatrixRank feature with symbolic computation

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

The current `MatrixRank` is a slight foolish without any capacity of symbolic computation ,feature of `Mathematica`, like this:

```
(mat = Normal@SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> a, 5, b]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
MatrixRank[mat]
(*5*)
```

But actually we expect the result in mathematics is:

```
when a=b=0,rank(mat)=0
when a=b≠0,rank(mat)=1
when a+4b=0,rank(mat)=4
when a≠b&&a≠-4b,rank(mat)=5
```

I'd like to be `Solve`'s result:

```
In[1]:= Solve[x^2 + y^2 + x == 1, y, Reals]

Out[1]= {{y -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[1 - x - x^2], 
    1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) < x < 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])]}, {y -> 
   ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[1 - x - x^2], 
    1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) < x < 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])]}}
```

It will give a `ConditionalExpression` for every result.And I think the `Mathematica` can do it via some solution.like following we can find some condition for this:

[image]

But I don't know what I should to do next for this.So help Mathematica,help me to improve or rewrite the `MatrixRank`,give some thinking,please.

Comment: First you will want to know what makes eigenvalues vanish. That can be found as follows. `In[10]:= roots = x /. Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, x] == 0, x]

Out[10]= {a - b, a - b, a - b, a - b, a + 4 b}`. Next take all subsets and invoke something like `Solve[subset==0&&Complement[set,subset]!=0]` to find all cases where rank= #subset. In this case of course it simplifies since there is a repeated root, but this should give the general idea.

Comment: Can you post an arranged answer that I can accept it?And it will be helpful to another to read it.

Comment: One other possibility is similar to Daniel's solution, except that what I had in mind was to use `LUDecomposition[]`, and then do the checks described by Daniel on the diagonal entries of the upper triangular factor.

Comment: The approach by @J.M. might be more sensible since it reduces the possibility of working over an algebraic extension to the case of finally checking subsets. But I think there is then a new complication, of rechecking such cases to see what happens next (heuristic reason: if a potential pivot were to vanish, that does not mean there is no other possible pivot).

Comment: @J.M. Done. :) $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MatrixRankSym[mat_] := Module[{smallDim, zero, full},
  If[AllTrue[Flatten[mat], NumberQ], Return[MatrixRank[mat]]];
  smallDim = Min[Dimensions[mat]];
  zero = Reduce[Thread[Flatten[mat] == 0]];
  full = If[SquareMatrixQ[mat], Reduce[Det[mat] != 0], 
    Reduce[Or @@ Thread[Flatten[Minors[mat, smallDim]] != 0]]];
  If[smallDim >= 2, 
   Piecewise[
    Join[{{smallDim, full}}, 
     Table[{dim, 
       Reduce[Or @@ Thread[Flatten[Minors[mat, dim]] != 0] && 
         And @@ Thread[Flatten[Minors[mat, dim + 1]] == 0]]}, {dim, 
       Range[smallDim - 1, 1, -1]}], {{0, zero}}], Indeterminate], 
   Piecewise[Join[{{0, zero}}, {{smallDim, full}}], Indeterminate]]]
```

---

## Usage:

```
mat = Normal@SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> a, 5, b];
MatrixRankSym[mat]
```

[image]

```
mat2 = {{3 x^2, 3 y^2, 3 z^2}, {1, 1, 1}};
MatrixRankSym[mat2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is not a complete solution but should provide a start. In the special case of a square matrix we can determine conditions on rank by determining where specific numbers of eigenvalues vanish. We show how to set this up using the example from the post.

```
mat = Normal@SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> a, 5, b]

(* Out[17]= {{a, b, b, b, b}, {b, a, b, b, b}, {b, b, a, b, b}, {b, b, b,
   a, b}, {b, b, b, b, a}} *)

roots = x /. Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, x] == 0, x]

(* Out[18]= {a - b, a - b, a - b, a - b, a + 4 b} *)
```

To proceed from here one could do as follows.

For each subset `sroots` of `roots`, do `Reduce[Flatten[Thread[sroots==0],Thread[Complement[roots,sroots]!=0]]]`. If `sroots` has size `n` then this gives a set of conditions for the rank to be exactly `n`.

This will take some real work to make efficient in those cases where, as above, there are (generically) repeated roots.

Comment: Does `x /. Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, x] == 0, x]` do anything that `Eigenvalues[mat]` can't do?

Comment: @J.M. No, of course not, I'm just fuzzy this morning.

Comment: `sol = SolveValues[CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, x] == 0, x];
Piecewise[
 Table[{n, Reduce[n == Total[Boole[Thread[sol != 0]]]]}, {n, 5, 
   0, -1}], Indeterminate]` can do indeed, but `CharacteristicPolynomial` require a square matrix

Answer (score 3):

#### Max Rank

I use the following function to check if the matrix is of a maximum rank:

```
(* Max Rank? *)
MRQ[m_] := Minors[m, Min[Dimensions[m]]] != 0;
```

Usage example:

```
Reduce[MRQ[{{3 x^2, 3 y^2, 3 z^2}, {1, 1, 1}}], {x, y, z}]
```

results in:

```
x^2 - y^2 != 0 || x^2 - z^2 != 0 || y^2 - z^2 != 0
```

or

```
Solve[! MRQ[{{3 x^2 - 6 y, -6 x + 2 y}}], {x, y}]
```

in

```
{{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 6, y -> 18}}
```

Comment: Note that the question asks for something to **compute the matrix's rank**, not to check if the matrix's rank is maximal.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but a good start

```
Join[{#, MatrixRank[mat /. #]} & /@ 
  Flatten[{ToRules[
     Reduce[Det[mat] == 0, a]]}], {If[(fullRank = 
      Reduce[Det[mat] > 0, a, Reals]) =!= False, {fullRank, 5}, 
   Nothing]}]
```

> {{a -> -4 b, 4}, {a -> b, 
>     1}, {(b <= 0 && a > -4 b) || (b > 0 && (-4 b < a < b || a > b)), 5}}

But I don't know how to deal the case when rank is $0$