# How to solve this equation with matrix rank condition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

It is known that quadratic form $f\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)=x_{1}^{2}-4 x_{1} x_{2}+4 x_{2}^{2}$ can be transformed into quadratic form $g\left(y_{1}, y_{2}\right)=a y_{1}^{2}+4 x_{1} x_{2}+6 y_{2}^{2}$ by orthogonal transformation (It is known that matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ll}
a & 2 \\
2 & b
\end{array}\right)$ and matrix  $\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & -2 \\
-2 & 4
\end{array}\right)$ are congruent matrices under orthogonal transformation).

Now I want to find the value of `a`, `b`.

```
  Solve[Det[{{a, 2}, {2, b}}] == Det[{{1, -2}, {-2, 4}}] && 
      MatrixRank[{{a, 2}, {2, b}}] == MatrixRank[{{1, -2}, {-2, 4}}], {a, 
      b}]
```

But the above code returns an empty set after being run (the answer is `{a->4,b->1}`). What can I do to solve this matrix equation?

**Updated content:**

**In addition**, for the three-dimensional case, how to find the solution of the following matrix equation quickly:

```
Q = Array[x, {3, 3}]; 
A = {{1 - a, 1 + a, 0}, {1 + a, 1 - a, 0}, {0, 0, 2}} /. a -> 2; 
FindInstance[
 Thread[Transpose[Q] . A . Q == {{-4, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}], 
 Flatten[Q], Reals]
```

Since `Q` is required to be a real matrix, the above code has been running and cannot return results.

**Other examples for testing:**

```
A = {{a, 0, 1}, {0, a, -1}, {1, -1, a - 1}};  
Transpose[Q] . A . Q == {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

Comment: Should the two matrices have the same eigenvalues? If so, that would give two relatively simple equations. I don't think that your equations have a finite solution set.

Comment: @mikado Yes, two contract matrices under orthogonal transformation are also similar to each other. But I want to solve this matrix equation directly without any skill.

Comment: "I want to solve this matrix equation directly without any skill." -- Oh. Otherwise, I would have suggested that you use `A = {{a, 2}, {2, b}};
B = {{1, -2}, {-2, 4}}; Solve[{Det[A] == Det[B], Tr[A] == Tr[B]}, {a, b}]` instead. Two symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices have the same eigenvalues if and only if their trace and determinant coincide...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too hard to do, if you recall that one can use a rotation matrix to perform the required orthogonal similarity transformation:

```
{{{a, 2}, {2, b}}, TrigExpand[RotationMatrix[2 ArcTan[u]]]} /. 
 Solve[With[{rot = TrigExpand[RotationMatrix[2 ArcTan[u]]]}, 
            Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[rot.{{a, 2}, {2, b}}.Transpose[rot] ==
                                     {{1, -2}, {-2, 4}}]]],
       {a, b, u}]
   {{{{1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{-(3/5), 4/5}, {-(4/5), -(3/5)}}},
    {{{4, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}},
    {{{1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{3/5, -(4/5)}, {4/5, 3/5}}},
    {{{4, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}}}
```

Note also the use of the Weierstrass substitution to ease the algebra done by `Solve[]`.

As an example verification,

```
{{0, -1}, {1, 0}}.{{4, 2}, {2, 1}}.Transpose[{{0, -1}, {1, 0}}] == {{1, -2}, {-2, 4}}
   True
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How to extend it to the case of three-dimensional matrix? `A = {{a, 0, 1}, {0, a, -1}, {1, -1, a - 1}}; 
Transpose[Q] . A . Q == {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}` I want to find the expression of the matrix `Q`.

Comment: That should be a separate question.

Comment: You can answer this question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228429/how-to-find-a-solution-of-this-matrix-equation-quickly). I have prepared a reward for you.

Comment: I have updated this question and hope you can update your answer.

Comment: You have misinterpreted my recommendation; I said that you should [ask a new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for the $3\times 3$ case, since that is no longer related to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The build-in function `MatrixRank` cannot work in symbolic matrix. So I make a symbolic version `MatrixRankSym` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97093/how-write-a-new-matrixrank-feature-with-symbolic-computation), then:

```
Reduce[Det[{{a, 2}, {2, b}}] == Det[{{1, -2}, {-2, 4}}] && 
  MatrixRankSym[{{a, 2}, {2, b}}] == MatrixRank[{{1, -2}, {-2, 4}}], {a, b}]
```

> a!=0&&b==4/a