# How to solve this equation with rank relation of matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

It has been known that matrix `A` is equivalent to matrix `B`, and  I want to find the possible value of parameter `a` (the answer is `a = 2`). This question is slightly different from that of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213111/how-to-solve-this-matrix-equation).

```
A = {{1, 2, a}, {1, 3, 0}, {2, 7, -a}}; 
B = {{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}; 
Solve[MatrixRank[A] == MatrixRank[B], a]
```

The above code can not output the correct results, I need your help.

**Besides, I have another question.**
I find that `RowReduce`-function can't make the matrix with parameters into row simplest type:

```
RowReduce[{{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]
```

The row simplest form of matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$ should be $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & a-2 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ instead of $\left(\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$. I wonder if this error is **a bug** in the `RowReduce` function.

**In addition**, sometimes it is necessary to deal with the following non square matrix equation:

```
A = {{1, -1, -1}, {2, a, 1}, {-1, 1, a}}; B = {{2, 2}, {1, 
   a}, {-a - 1, -2}}; 
Solve[MatrixRank[A] == 
    MatrixRank[Join[A, B, 2]], a, Reals]
```

Comment: To address the last question: This is not a bug in `RowReduce` (nor is it an error).

Comment: 1. There is no bug here. 2. You should know by now that the [tag:bugs] tag is not to be applied unless other people have confirmed that what you've seen is a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau If it's not a bug I would argue, though, that the documentation does a pretty bad job at explaining this limitation. Would it be feasible for `RowReduce` to have a `GenerateConditions` option to at least be able to keep track of the conditions that that make the reduced form valid?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit (1) I don't think such an option is likely to be added but in theory it is feasible. One way to obtain such information is to augment the matrix with an identity matrix on the right (as though finding a matrix inverse as taught in linear algebra), then row reduce, then take denominators in the augmented section as nonvanishing conditions.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit (2) See also [this old response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179478/574643) to a similar question, for adapting the `ZeroTest` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `RowReduce` and `MatrixRank` implicitly assume that `a` does not have a particular value that reduces the rank of the matrix. They can detect that matrix `A` is degenerate for any value of `a`, but not that `B` is degenerate for `a == 2`.

I think you might be able to get around this with `SingularValueList`, which seems to handle the problem better:

```
Assuming[a \[Element] Reals,
  Simplify[Reduce[Simplify[#] == 0] & /@ SingularValueList[A]]
]
Assuming[a \[Element] Reals,
  Simplify[Reduce[Simplify[#] == 0] & /@ SingularValueList[B]]
]
```

> {False, False}

> {a == 2, False, False}

From this you can see that `A` always has rank 2 while `B` has rank 3 any value of `a` other than 2.

## Edit

Here's a quick attempt to do what you asked directly:

```
symbolicMatrixRank[mat_, assumptions_] := Assuming[assumptions,
   Simplify @ Total @ Simplify[
     Boole[!Reduce[Simplify[#] == 0]] & /@ SingularValueList[mat]
   ]
];
Solve[symbolicMatrixRank[A, a ∈ Reals] == symbolicMatrixRank[B, a ∈ Reals]]
```

> {{a -> 2}}

or similarly:

```
symbolicMatrixRank[mat_, assumptions_] := Assuming[assumptions,
  Simplify @ Total @ Map[
    Boole @ Simplify @ Reduce[ConditionalExpression[#, $Assumptions] != 0]&,
    SingularValueList[mat]
  ]
];
```

As noted in a comment, `Solve` doesn't not always seem to deal with these sort of piecewise equations too well. `Resolve` is more adapt at solving them.

Comment: Your answer is great, but how to deal with the following non square matrix equation:`A = {{1, -1, -1}, {2, a, 1}, {-1, 1, a}}; B = {{2, 2}, {1, 
   a}, {-a - 1, -2}}; 
Solve[symbolicMatrixRank[A, Element[a, Reals]] == 
     symbolicMatrixRank[Join[A, B, 2], Element[a, Reals]]]`.

Comment: @Montevideo For some reason `Solve` doesn't handle this very well. Try `Reduce` instead. It should give you `2 + a != 0`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. Why can't the following code return the correct result ({a -> 2, b -> -3}):`mat = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 5, -1}, {a, 1, 3, b}}; 
augmat = {{1, 1, 1, 1, -1}, {4, 3, 5, -1, -1}, {a, 1, 3, b, 1}}; 
symbolicMatrixRank[mat_, assumptions_] := 
    Assuming[assumptions, 
  Simplify[Total[
    Simplify[(Boole[ ! Reduce[Simplify[#1] == 0]] & ) /@ 
      SingularValueList[mat]]]]]; 
Reduce[symbolicMatrixRank[mat, 
   Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals]] == 
     symbolicMatrixRank[augmat, 
   Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals]] == 2]`.

Comment: @Montevideo Try the second form of `symbolicMatrixRank` I put in my answer. That one works here. Depending on the returned value of `SingularValueList`, you may need to wrangle a little with how you call `Reduce` and `Simplify`. I won't claim that these functions work for every imaginable matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't used the second method. I thought they were exactly the same.

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you again. No matter what kind of definition of function `symbolicMatrixRank` is used in the following code, the desired result (`a + b + c = =0`) cannot be obtained: `Reduce[symbolicMatrixRank[{{a, 2*b}, {b, 2*c}, {c, 2*a}}, 
       Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals] && Element[c, Reals]] == 
     symbolicMatrixRank[{{a, 2*b, -3*c}, {b, 2*c, -3*a}, {c, 
     2*a, -3*b}}, 
       Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals] && Element[c, Reals]] == 
  2]`.

Comment: @Montevideo Please ask a new question. The comments aren't the right place for this.

Comment: If you have time, I hope you can answer [my new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228795/how-to-solve-this-kind-of-matrix-equation-related-to-rank). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Montevideo I'm a bit busy atm, but I'll have a look when I have time.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a `MatrixRankSym` feature with symbolic computation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262568/21532). And we can use it directly:

**For your first equation:**

```
A = {{1, 2, a}, {1, 3, 0}, {2, 7, -a}};
B = {{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}};
Reduce[MatrixRankSym[A] == MatrixRankSym[B], a]
```

> a == 2

**For your second non square matrix equation:**

```
A = {{1, -1, -1}, {2, a, 1}, {-1, 1, a}};
B = {{2, 2}, {1, a}, {-a - 1, -2}};
Reduce[MatrixRankSym[A] == MatrixRankSym[Join[A, B, 2]], a, Reals]
```

> a < -2 || a > -2