# How to solve this kind of matrix equation related to rank

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I saw a post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227929/how-to-solve-this-equation-with-rank-relation-of-matrix?noredirect=1#comment580672_227929) to solve the rank relation equation of matrix:

```
symbolicMatrixRank[mat_, assumptions_] := Assuming[assumptions,
  Simplify @ Total @ Map[
    Boole @ Simplify @ Reduce[ConditionalExpression[#, $Assumptions] != 0]&,
    SingularValueList[mat]
  ]
];

adj[m_](*adjoint matrix*):= 
 Map[Reverse, Minors[Transpose[m], Length[m] - 1], {0, 1}]*
  Table[(-1)^(i + j), {i, Length[m]}, {j, Length[m]}]

Reduce[symbolicMatrixRank[adj[{{a, b, b}, {b, a, b}, {b, b, a}}], 
       Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals]] == 1]
```

The custom function `symbolicMatrixRank` of **Sjoerd Smit** is great. But I find that the following matrix equation cannot be solved by the above method:

```
Reduce[symbolicMatrixRank[{{a, 2*b}, {b, 2*c}, {c, 2*a}}, 
       Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals] && Element[c, Reals]] == 
     symbolicMatrixRank[{{a, 2*b, -3*c}, {b, 2*c, -3*a}, {c, 
     2*a, -3*b}}, 
       Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals] && Element[c, Reals]] == 
  2]
```

How can I improve the above code so that I can solve the kind of matrix equation?

**Note:** The following questions are from the 10th question of the [2003 Chinese Graduate Mathematical Entrance Examination](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/60dbbc586d85ec3a87c24028915f804d2a16876e.html) (first set).

The reference answer of this question is `a + b + c = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only managed to get this one by just messing around with the singular values until some combination of `Reduce` and `Simplify` yielded something legible:

```
mat1 = {{a, 2*b}, {b, 2*c}, {c, 2*a}}
mat2 = {{a, 2*b, -3*c}, {b, 2*c, -3*a}, {c, 2*a, -3*b}}
assumptions = {a, b, c} \[Element] Reals

rank1 = Assuming[assumptions,
  Total[
   Boole @ Simplify @ Reduce @ Reduce[# != 0 && assumptions] & /@ SingularValueList[mat1]
  ]
]
rank2 = Assuming[assumptions,
  Total[
   Boole @ Simplify @ Reduce @ Reduce[# != 0 && assumptions] & /@ SingularValueList[mat2]
  ]
]

Simplify[Reduce[assumptions && rank1 == rank2], Assumptions -> assumptions]
```

> (c != 0 && ((a == c && b == c) || a + b + c == 0)) || (a + b == 0 &&
> c == 0)